# SCALA How to parse json back to the controller?

Tags: json, scala

I am new to Scala. I want to parse JSON data in scala store to database table.

My GET method looks like this (Please ignore the permissions):

```
def Classes = withAuth { username =>
implicit request =>
  User.access(username, User.ReadXData).map { user =>
    implicit val writer = new Writes[Class] {
      def writes(entry: Class): JsValue = Json.obj(
        "id" -> entry.id,
        "name" -> entry.name
      )
    }
    val classes = (Class.allAccessible(user))
    Ok(Json.obj("success" -> true, "classes" -> classes))
  }.getOrElse(Forbidden(Application.apiMessage("Not authorised"))) }
```

This GET method returns the json below:

```
"success":true,"schools":[{"id":93,"name":"Happy unniversity",}]}
```

I'm currently rendering the JSOn in a datatables js ([editor](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/simple.html)) grid - with success

HOWEVER, I'm unable to parse and POST the JSON and store it to the database (mysql) table.

Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: I'm afraid your question is a bit too broad and underspecified to be answerable. Specifically, it would be good to mention which backend framework you're using (your example looks like playframework, but would be nice to confirm, and share the  endpoints specification (`routes` file in Play, or whichever your framework uses). And maybe a short, sufficient example from the "controller" (i.e. all that's relevant) (hint: instead of saying "Please ignore the permissions" you might just remove them from the example :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks you are using play-json.

For class User

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

final case class User(id: String, name: String)

object User {
  implicit val userFormat = Json.format[User]
}

object UserJson {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val user = User("11", "Peter")

    val json = Json.toJson(user).toString()
    println("json ===> " + json)

    val user2 = Json.parse(json).as[User]

    println("name ===> " + user2.name)

  }

}
```

I definitely recommend this lib: "de.heikoseeberger" %% "akka-http-jackson" % "1.27.0" for akka-http.

Comment: That's true, but I think a bit oversimplified - OP asks for POSTing it back to the application

Comment: Actually, depends on the web framework. If using akka-http,  need to look at 
akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.

I definitely recommend this lib: "de.heikoseeberger" %% "akka-http-jackson" % "1.27.0"

Comment: For the sake of argument :) Why not circe, play-json, spray, or any other "native" scala Json library.

Comment: play-json, spray need to write implicit method. it is boring, besides that,  play-json, spray also has 22 fields problem.  

BTW play-json and akka-http-jackson are both based on Jackson(fast-xml).

Comment: A matter of taste I guess. If 22 fields is a limitation there's probably already something wrong with the rest of the "design" :) Formatters are boilerplate, yes, but that's a relatively small price to pay for being able to pattern match on the outputs and not to worry about exceptions thrown. Also it enables some further improvements (like "applicative" parsing that reports all the errors, not just the first one - not sure though if Jackson does that as well). But I also see your point - again, probably a matter of taste.